# Overwriting parts of a string with parts of another string

Tags: c, string, memcpy, strncpy

I'm trying to overwrite a part of a string with parts of another String.

Basically, I want to access a given index of a string, write a given number of chars from another given index of another string.

So a function like `memcpy(stringa[indexa], stringb[indexb], length);`, except that this does not work.

Using `strncpy` would also suffice.

More code, as requested:

```
void mymemset(char* memloc, char* cmd, int data_blocks[], int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < len)
    {
        //missing part. Where I want the "memcpy" operation to take place
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

`memloc` is the string we want to overwrite, `cmd` is the string we are overwriting from, `data_blocks` contains information about where in `memloc` we are supposed to write, and `len` is the number of operations we are executing. So I want to overwrite at location `data_blocks[i]`, from `cmd` 8 chars at a time.

EDIT: I think I just forgot an `&`, so sorry to have confused you and thanks for your time. This seems to work:

```
void mymemset(char* memloc, char* cmd, int data_blocks[], int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < len)
    {
        memcpy(&memloc[data_blocks[i]], &cmd[i*8], 8);
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Takes 8 bytes at a time from `cmd`, stores them in `memloc` at the index given by `data_blocks[i]`. As commented, `data_blocks` contains information about different indexes in `memloc` that is available, and segmentation of the string `cmd` can occur.

Comment: `mymemset` is unrelated to your question, and BTW it is complete nonsense.

Comment: You have to be very careful not to write beyond the end of the destination string.

Comment: ... and what is `data_blocks` supposed to be ? Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I tried to clarify. Whats the point in being rude? @JoachimPileborg thanks, I am already taking care of this in another part of the program, the one assigning values to `data_blocks`.

Comment: @hewo i am not quite sure I follow why you pass an array of ints to the function, shouldn't it be just one value from the array, not the whole array or do you write the same characters in several places in memloc but all with same length?

Comment: @hewo what have you tried so far part from writing the prototype? We are not Homework'R'Us

Comment: @Claptrap I pass an array because I need to segment the string `cmd` into parts of 8 bytes, and store them in turn in the string `memloc`. The segments may be located at different indexes of `memloc`, and the indexes are kept in the array. I know you are not to do my homework, the task at hand is far beyond this function, but I thought this question was so general and technical (hence my sparse code in the beginning) that it was completely within what SO is meant for.

Comment: @hewo seems you have solved your problem, good job!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `stringa` and `stringb` are declared as follows

```
char stringa[] = "Hello" ;
char stringb[] = "World" ;
```

This should work:

```
memcpy(&stringa[1], &stringb[1], 2) ;
```

Your example should not compile, or if it compiles if is likely to crash or to cause undefined behaviour :

```
memcpy(stringa[1], stringb[1], 2) ;
```

Comment: I will try this first, I might just have messed up my first attempts because of a missing `&`

Answer (score 0):

Your naming is confusing : `memset` works on bytes. If you manipulate strings you have extra precaution to take: think of the `\0`.

I think you want something like that:

```
void my_str_overwrite(char* dest, const char* ref, int idx, size_t count)
{
    size_t input_len = strlen(dest);
    if(input_len <= idx+count)
    {
        // Error: not enough space
    }
    for(size_t i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        dest[idx+i] = ref[i];
    }
    return;
}
```

- You don't need to pass the whole `data_block[]` array, you just interested in one element of this array which contains an offset for your copy, if I understood correctly.
- As you don't modify `cmd` it should be `const`
- The code above does not handle the NULL terminating byte which should be appended to `memloc` if it is actually a string

> So I want to overwrite at location data_blocks[i], from cmd **8 chars at a time.**

This one is confusing. If you know that you only want 8 bytes to be copied each time you call the function then in the code above make `count` an local variable within the function and fix it `size_t count = 8;`

Comment: I'm sorry for the cunfusion, but the system functions by storing 8 bytes at a time, so I will always ready 8 bytes at a time, never caring for the `\0` (at least during memory management, obviously `\0` must be added again before using the concatenated string).

Comment: You can check one of my comments longer up for why I pass an array of ints

Answer (score 0):

if strings are the same size the you can just use memcpy:

```
#include <strings.h>

char text[] = "Hello James!";
char name[] = "Jenny";
char* pos = strstr(text, "James");
memcpy(pos, name, strlen(name)-1); // for the '\0'
```

If they're not then you must reallocate the string as the length will change

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define STR "Hello James!"

void replace(char** src, char* find, char* rep) {
    char* ret = NULL;
    char* pos = strstr(*src, find);
    if (!pos)
        return; // no changes
    int l = (1 + strlen(*src) + strlen(rep) - strlen(find));
    ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * l);
    ret[l-1] = 0;

    int ind = (int)(pos - *src);
    strncpy(ret, *src, ind);
    printf("ind: %d; %s\n", ind, ret);
    strncpy(&ret[ind], rep, strlen(rep));
    strncpy(&ret[ind+strlen(rep)], &pos[strlen(find)], strlen(pos)-strlen(find));
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    free(*src);
    *src = ret;
}

int main() {
    char *str = NULL;
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(STR)+1));
    assert(str);
    strcpy(str, STR);
    printf("before: %s\n", str);
    replace(&str, "James", "John");
    printf("after: %s\n", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

This code in not optimized.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm sure your solution works, but I want to avoid freeing and reallocating the destination string. Also I only know the index I want to start at, so `strstr` is not needed.

Comment: Well if you are certain you will not overflow the string length then you can directly use strcpy. I'm going to update the post so it fits the non allocation policy.